# Return register of floating point math x86

Tags: x86

What register holds the return after calling a function which returns a float or double?

```
float domath() {
 return .1230+.2323
}
```

Comment: About 5-6 abstractions deeper than this code, i think most FPU registers will be used. Why do you want Register access when doing a higher level language?

Comment: Im trying to learn x86 and I want to understand how C translates to the instructions

Comment: C doesn't translate as such. C is a language specification (huge) of logical constructs. There are many C compilers and each one has slightly different approaches of how to assemble/optimize the opcodes usable by the processor. The results that you will get will be very specific to the C compiler used.  Better try to get a grasp of ASM by doing some ASM before trying to translate ASM->C where one is unknown to you.

Comment: Doesn't your compiler/debugger have assembly output? Then you can at least see what your particular compiler/linker combination generates.